# Download specific Tag Source

Tags: c#, webclient

I have some web pages with A lot of tags.i want to download source Page where it tag is `Span` and its `className` is `Something`.

It's possible that i just download a part of page(source code) not whole page?

I know that i can do it with `webbrowser`(for example navigate to my destination page and search for specific tag and get its source code)
But with it,i must first get whole page and after that get specific tag.

there is any way (for example: `WebClient` class) to download just my specific tag with specific `ClassName` source code?

Answer (score 2):

No, the HTTP protocol doesn't have any facility to do what you need (the only thing one can do is get a certain Range, but that requires you to know exactly where the data is, so that doesn't seem to help), you will have to download the entire page and then parse what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you cannot download just parts of your page and you need to load the whole page first. But to make it maybe easier, you can parse the HTML in XML and then work with it which is a lot easier.